# SQL Update error: spaces truncate strings

Tags: sql, truncated

I'm having a problem with sql.

When I try updating like this:

```
UPDATE Event SET name = 'bla bla bla' WHERE id = 2
```

It gives me this error:

> String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated.

However, when I try updating with one space less, like this:

```
UPDATE Event SET name = 'bla bla' WHERE id = 2
```

It works fine. How come? Any inputs on how to go around this error would be appreciated.

Comment: Probably because the name column in the Event table is less than 9 characters long.

Comment: yeah, length is set to 10... thanks

Comment: No problem. It's an issue everyone has, oh about a zillion times over their career.

Comment: yeah I seem to get stuck longer on trivial problems. fml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the space.  The longer string is too long for `name`.

Look at the definition of `name`.  You'll see that `'bla bla bla'` is too long for it.  But `'bla bla'` fits.

Comment: damn! the length is set to 10! ive been stuck at this for an hour and couldnt figure it out! lol. THANKS